# In loops, does a compiler really call a function that returns the same value on each iteration?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I tested a code (not this actually, here is just a simplified version):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto f() {
    //imagine a lot of instructions before the last line
    return std::vector{1, 2};
}

int main() {

    auto vec = f();

    for (auto i : vec)
    std::cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

And I got stuck to that moment:

```
auto vec = f();
for (auto i : vec)
```

Can I use `for (auto i : f())` instead? The output shows the same.

I know about cache-level optimization. The result of function is saved, so if we invoke it with the same parameters, we don't need to evaluate the answer again. But I'm wondering is there any compiler optimization?

I had used godbolt.org but I didn't find it useful.

Comment: Yes this is possible due to how range based for loops are defined. f() is invoked only once. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: This has nothing to do with caching, I even suspect you get the same compiler output with or without the temporary variable (release build + optimized)

Comment: `for (auto i : f())` evaluates `f()` only once. (unrelated to optimization level).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use for (auto i : f()) instead?

The only difference between that and the original is that the temporary materialized from the call to `f()` will live only until the end of the range-for loop, while `vec` in the original will live until the end of the block in which it is declared.

Either way, `f()` is called exactly once.

In the example you gave any decent compiler will generate exactly the same or practically equivalent machine instructions. There would be a difference only if the exact point at which the `std::vector`'s destructor is called would matter.